# Reactjs with flexbox or bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I'm just learning Reactjs and a friend of mine highly suggested that I drop using bootstrap and go 100% Flexbox. I've looked into it and Flexbox seems definitely worth learning and it appears that React Native also uses a version Flexbox for mobile applications. I feel though that dropping bootstrap means that I drop all the cool multiple screen size re-sizing benefits and a lot of the outbox stuff like the navbar,panels, buttons ect and with Flexbox I'll have to custom build all of that stuff.

Will it be worth going with 100% Flexbox if my intent is to make nice mobile friendly web applications and possible convert over my stuff to React Native. Or would it be easier to stick with what I know to get up my web application now with possible less overall hassle and then make the switch to Flexbox later?

Thx in advance for any advice for a noob. :)

Comment: Bootstrap is far more than just layout, so I don't see how you can compare them. Flexbox is a bit buggy and inconsistent across browsers in some cases. Your experience may vary.

Comment: shameless-plug: consider this one? https://github.com/roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid
It is a set of React components implementing flexboxgrid.css with the power of CSS Modules. :)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't try to use the same patterns for building your web app and your React Native app. You might want to use different interface patterns.

React Native uses flexbox because it is trying to be forward thinking and doesn't have to worry about browser support, because the app is being converted to a native application.

If you're also building a web app you might want to consider browser support and current issues in the flexbox implementation.

See the following link for more information.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

An alternative would be to build your app as a full mobile web app using ReactJS and wrap the application with Cordova to get native apps. This way you can develop using the web development techniques you are already familiar with.